# styled-components strongly typed [theme] property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I am using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) TypeScript and `ThemeProvider` for my components, and I had a couple of questions:

1. First of all, my components are created using `map`, so I used to assign a `key` to each one, now I have put `ThemeProvider` to be the top parent component, and hence I need to set the `key` on that. I was just wondering does it hurt to do this? Or should I find a way to create a single `ThemeProvider`?
2. Since I'm using TypeScript, it would be very nice if I could somehow make my `props.theme` property be strongly typed. Right now when I hover over `props.theme`, I see that the type is `any`. It would VERY nice if I could somehow define the type for the `theme` property while not changing the inferred type for `props`

The problem I have right now is that when I define a custom `interface` for the `props` I'm using in a `styled` component, I loose the default properties inferred by the component. For example, if I want to have something like this:

```
interface ComponentProps {
  status: string;
}
```

Then, I create a component like this:

```
const MyComp = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(props: ComponentProps) => props.theme...};
`
```

Then, TypeScript will complain that `theme` doesn't exist on `ComponentProps`, but if I don't define the type for the `props`, then when I want to create my custom component:

```
<MyComp status="hello" />
```

Now, the TypeScript is complaining that property `status` doesn't apply to `MyComp`

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container, and pass any property you like. Like this:

in **styledWithProps.ts** file:

```js
import { ThemedStyledFunction } from 'styled-components';

export const styledWithProps = <U>() =>
    <P, T, O>(
        fn: ThemedStyledFunction<P, T, O>
    ): ThemedStyledFunction<P & U, T, O & U> => fn;
```

when using it:

```js
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";
import { styledWithProps } from "./styledWithProps.ts";

const MyComp = styledWithProps<any>()(styled.div) `
${props => props.theme==="dark" && css`
    background-color: black;
`}
`;

const app = props => <MyComp theme="dark">{props.children}</MyComp>
```

For more details, take a look this thread: https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/630